# How to create a new table td with inputs values from array with a loop? I'm puzzled

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, createelement

The first and last names are placed in the object, and the object is placed in the array. This array is saved by localStorage. After the form, let the table contain the information from the local storage array.

```
const jsonForm = document.querySelector('.json'),
    jsonInput = document.querySelector('.json-input'),
    jsonOutPut = document.querySelector('.json-table'),
    tdFirstname = jsonOutPut.querySelector('.first-name'),
    tdSecondName = jsonOutPut.querySelector('.second-name'),
    namesArr = [];

jsonForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const splitted = jsonInput.value.split(' ');
    let nameInput = splitted[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitted[0].slice(1);
    let surnameInput = splitted[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitted[1].slice(1);
    namesArr.sort();
    namesArr.push(nameInput);
    namesArr.push(surnameInput);
    console.log(namesArr);
    tdFirstname.append(namesArr[0]);
    tdSecondName.append(namesArr[1]);

});
```

```
  <form class="json">
    <input type="text" class="json-input">
    <button type="submit">Enter Your FullName</button>
  </form>
  <br><br>
  
  <table class="json-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="first-name"></td>
      <td class="second-name"></td>
    </tr>
    
  </table>
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem you hit? Is there an error, or something you expect, but is not happening at a certain point in your code above?

Comment: I need to display the entered names in a table, the first name is displayed well, but the next ones are displayed in a line, not in a new td

Comment: can you share your html too? It would help to have a working example showing the problem.

Comment: I want to deal with this, I don’t understand how to write a loop for creating new elements with values from input

Answer (score 1):

Content is always written to the same existing nodes again, instead of creating new nodes per entry. Something like this should work ([Codepen](https://codepen.io/eyecatchup/pen/ExbjWzz)):

```html
<form class="json">
  <input class="json-input">
  <button type="submit">Enter Your FullName</button>
</form>

<table class="json-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="json-data"></tbody>
</table>
```

```js
const addRowToTable = (str) => {
    const splitted = str.split(' ');
    const tr = document.createElement('tr');
    const td1 = document.createElement('td');
    const td2 = td1.cloneNode();
    td1.innerText = splitted[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitted[0].slice(1);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    if (splitted.length === 2) {
         td2.innerText = splitted[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitted[1].slice(1); 
    }
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    document.querySelector('.json-data').appendChild(tr);
}

const form = document.querySelector('.json');
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    addRowToTable(document.querySelector('.json-input').value);
    // save `document.querySelector('.json-input').value` to local storage
    form.reset();
});

// read local storage and use `addRowToTable` function to add existing entries to the table
```

Comment: Thank you, m8! It looks easier than I've thought.